# Avoid full table scan on a table Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, full-text-search

I have a table which has 70 columns, Where primary key is the combination of 15 columns (which includes number and varchar2) . Please see below query

```
select * from tab1 where k1=1234567889; 

Plan hash value: 1179808636
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |             |  6044 |  2201K|  4585K  (1)| 15:17:04 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| tab1        |  6044 |  2201K|  4585K  (1)| 15:17:04 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 – filter ("K1"=30064825087)
```

Where tab1 is a table mentions above and k1 is a column which is part of primary key. Table is not partitioned. Table is also analyzed (table, index and columns) after data has been inserted. Output for above query returns like 100000 plus records.  The problem is even after having PK on the k1 column, the query is doing full table scan, which is not acceptable. On the other hand using index hints does not really speed up the process.

Please advise what would be the possible solution.

Comment: PLease show the definition of K1 and the index definition on K1.

Comment: If there are 100,000+ rows with a particular `K1` value and using an index hint to force the index to be used doesn't improve performance (I assume that you're successfully forcing an index to be used), why do you believe that the full table scan is unacceptable?  It appears that you're saying that the optimizer's estimates are accurate and the full scan is the most efficient approach.  You might be able to improve performance of this query (though it may negatively affect other queries) by creating the table as an index-organized table or partitioning the table on `K1` (extra licensing cost).

Answer (score 2):

For this query:

```
select *
from tab1
where k1 = 1234567889;
```

The best index is one that has `k1` as the *first* key in the index.  There can be a composite index, by `k1` has to be the first key.  It sounds like you have a composite primary key and `k1` is not the first key.

I would recommend that you simply define another index:

```
create index idx_tab1_k1 on tab1(k1);
```

Comment: Cant have k1 in leading column name for  PK , because i already have another imp column as k0 as the leading column.

Comment: @Amod . . . That's why I suggest creating another index for that column.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to avoid a full-table scan

Indexes:  Ensure that indexes exist on the key value and that the index has been analyzed with dbms_stats.
Use_nl hint:  You can direct that the optimizer use a nested loops join (which requires indexes).
index hint:  You can specify the indexes that you want to use.